# add link or any html tag to column in django-datatables-view

Tags: python, django, datatable, datatables, django-datatable

I've got django-datatables-view looking like this:

```
class OrderListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = Flat
    columns = ['id', 'flat_price', 'flat_house.house_block.block_name']
    order_columns = ['flat_price', 'flat_house.house_block.block_name']
    max_display_length = 100

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(flat_price__lte=search)
        return qs
```

How to wrap `'flat_house.adress'` with `<a>` or any other html-tag? For example,`<a href="{% url 'id' %}"`. Right now I only show the data from the column in a `<td>` tag.

My html-template looks like this:

```
<table id="datatabletest" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>adress</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>adress</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this. [django-datatables-view](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view)

you can use render_column method for this.

```
    def render_column(self, row, column):
        # i recommend change 'flat_house.house_block.block_name' to 'address'
        if column == 'address':
            return '<a href="%s">link</a>' % row.flat_house.house_block.block_name
        else:
            return super(OrderListJson, self).render_column(row, column)
```